# Custom Icons not loading or working in leafetjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

any tips as to why my map won't load at all. It works without this piece of code. but even the default icon doesn't load any suggestions?

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: url('images/Icons/Cross_Map_Icon.png')
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],">
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],  
});

for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i, {icon:myIcon}) 
{
  L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lon] )
  .bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[i].website + '" target="_blank">' + 
   markers[i].Church+ '</a>' )
  .addTo(maped);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have a typo where you define the `iconAnchor` property. Did you mean for it look like this?

```
iconAnchor: [22, 94],
```

You might also need a comma after the `iconUrl` property. I think you might want the `myIcon` variable to look like this:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: url('images/Icons/Cross_Map_Icon.png'),
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],  
});
```